# Is it possible to show the order details sent to customer via email in a separate page (Magento)?

Tags: magento

Is it possible to show the order details of last processed order, such as

`Item   Sku   Qty   Subtotal`

in a separate page?

I tried adding the order details section from `frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml` in a separate cms page, by adding `{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}` to it.

But, when I run this cms page after order being placed, it shows the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getAllItems() on a non-object in D:\wamp\www\magento\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\email\order\items.phtml

Is this actually possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible.. its already present in the magento system, when user places an order successfully they are shown with order number and a link to order details page.

the link to order page is like http://www.example.com/sales/order/view/order_id/25/

we can make system to be redirected directly to this page to accomplish this task.
the only this we needed is the order id this can be get using

Mage::getSingleton("checkout/session")->getLastOrderId();

Answer (score 0):

Yes, most things are possible.  You'd have to write your own module, with your own controller which would serve up your own template.  There you can load up an order and display whatever you want.

Obviously, that isn't the answer you are hoping for, but your question isn't specific, and writing out how to accomplish what you want could easily take an entire blog article.